# Нужна ли запятая после союза «и»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова, сложное-предложение, и

Объясните, пожалуйста, постановку знаков препинания в данном предложении.

**На березках вместо листочков висят золотые монетки, и, кажется, что от одного дуновения ветерка они начнут тут же звенеть.**

Answer (score 2):

Слово "кажется" в данном случае не вводное слово, а сказуемое неполного предложения, поэтому после "и" запятая не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

**На березках вместо листочков висят золотые монетки, и кажется, что от одного дуновения ветерка они начнут тут же звенеть.**
(Без лишней запятой после союза "и".)

1. Упростим предложение: *Висят монетки, и кажется, что они начнут звенеть.*
   Слово "кажется" в этом предложении — это форма настоящего времени третьего лица единственного числа глагола "казаться"; является сказуемым (в односоставном безличном предложении).
2. "Кажется" нельзя изъять из предложения без потери смысла. (Сравните: *Висят монетки, и что они начнут звенеть.*) Вывод: вводным словом оно не является.

[Слово «кажется»](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/punktuatsiya/kazhetsya-vyidelyaetsya-zapyatyimi.html)